# How to copy an array of strings to a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, string, struct

How can I copy the contents of an array of strings to a struct? Getting error that it cannot convert type string to type string. The last loop is where I am having trouble. Do I need to allocate space on the heap for the string array too? I allocated it for the scores. I thought a string was really an array of characters so I am confused how to use pointers to reference and transfer them.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    struct StudentRecords
    {
     string* namesRec;
     int** examsptr;
     };


    void main()
    {


const int NG = 4;

string names[] = { "Amy Adams", "Bob Barr", "Carla Carr",
                     "Dan Dobbs", "Elena Evans" };

int exams[][NG] = 
{ 
    { 98,87,93,88 },
    { 78,86,82,91 },
    { 66,71,85,94 },
    { 72,63,77,69 },
    { 91,83,76,60 }
};

string *nameHolder = nullptr;


StudentRecords *data = new StudentRecords();
data->examsptr = new int*[NG];

for (int i = 0; i < NG; ++i) 
{
    data->examsptr[i] = new int[NG];
}

for (int count = 0; count < NG; count++)
{
    for (int count2 = 0; count2 < NG; count2++)
        {
         (*data).examsptr[count][count2] = exams[count][count2];
         cout << (*data).examsptr[count][count2] << "         " << exams[count][count2] << endl;
        }
     }

    for (int count3 = 0; count3 < 5; count3++)
    {
   *nameHolder = names[count3];
   (*data).namesRec[count3] = *nameHolder;
    cout << (*data).namesRec[count3] << endl;
     }
```

Comment: Btw. `(*data).` is the same as `data->`

Comment: `nameHolder` is a  null pointer and then you write `*nameHolder =`

Comment: Why don't you have `StudentRecords` point at the existing arrays, instead of trying to make a copy

Comment: initialize `string* namesRec` , you use it like array! so do `new` on him!
and this not c++, it C programs, can use vector or list ....

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize `data->namesRec = new string[size];` because is pointer!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use raw pointers to represent arrays.

Don't try to manage `new` and `delete` on your own, it's just error prone as proven from your code in question.

Use the appropriate container classes like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), or [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) provided by the c++ standard class library instead.

If your professor or TA denies to do so, just leave the course, they're not teaching c++.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct StudentRecords
{
    char* namesRec;
    int** examsptr;
};


void main(void)
{
    const int NG = 4;

    char *names[] = { "Amy Adams", "Bob Barr", "Carla Carr",
                        "Dan Dobbs", "Elena Evans" };

    int exams[][NG] = 
    { 
        { 98,87,93,88 },
        { 78,86,82,91 },
        { 66,71,85,94 },
        { 72,63,77,69 },
        { 91,83,76,60 },
    };

    char *nameHolder = nullptr;
    nameHolder = (char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));

    struct StudentRecords *data = new StudentRecords();
    data->examsptr = new int*[NG];

    for (int i = 0; i < NG; i++) 
    {
        data->examsptr[i] = new int[NG];
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < NG; count++)
    {
        for (int count2 = 0; count2 < NG; count2++)
        {
            data->examsptr[count][count2] = exams[count][count2];
            printf("%d ",data->examsptr[count][count2]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int count3 = 0; count3 < 5; count3++)
    {
        strcpy(nameHolder,names[count3]);
        data->namesRec = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(data->namesRec,names[count3]);
        printf("%s ",data->namesRec);
        free(data->namesRec);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NG;i++) 
    {
        delete data->examsptr[i];
    }
    delete data;
    free(nameHolder);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't mix `malloc` and `new`. At some point you are likely to call `delete` on a `malloc`ed resource or `free` on a `new`ed resource and then it will be Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: It's so bad coding, in c++ never use `malloc` not in this case... and if we do `malloc` must use `free()`. and c++ have `new` and `delete` !

Answer (score 0):

Just an hint:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Student {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<int> exams;
};


int main() {
    std::vector<Student> sList{ {"Amy Adams",   { 98,87,93,88 }},
                                {"Bob Barr",    { 78,86,82,91 }},
                                {"Carla Carr",  { 66,71,85,94 }},
                                {"Dan Dobbs",   { 72,63,77,69 }}};

    std::string sname = "Elena Evans";    // Just arrived...
    int exms[] = { 91,83,76,60 };         // if you need to use an array
    sList.push_back(Student{sname, {exms,exms+sizeof(exms)/sizeof(int)}}); 

    // show students
    for ( auto & s : sList ) {       // for every element of the vector
        std::cout << s.name << ": \t";
        for ( auto & e : s.exams ) std::cout << e << "  ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you are not allowed for some reason to use standard library containers and facilities you can at least try to mimic their capabilities and write some functions to manage the copies, allocations and deallocations:

```
std::string * _AllocNames( size_t n ) {
    std::string * new_ptr;
    try {
        new_ptr = new std::string[n];
        return new_ptr;
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc &ba) {       // Something bad happened
        std::cerr << "Error, exception caught: " << ba.what() << '\n';
        exit(1);
    }
}

void _DeAllocNames( std::string * names ) {
    if ( names ) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nStd; i++) names[i].clear();
        delete[] names;
    }
}

int ** _AllocExams( size_t n, size_t m ) {
    int ** new_ptr;
    try {
         new_ptr = new int*[n];
         for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) new_ptr[i] = new int[m];
         return new_ptr;
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc &ba) {       // Something bad happened
         std::cerr << "Error, exception caught: " << ba.what() << '\n';
         exit(1);
    }
}


void _DeAllocExams( int ** exams ) {
     if ( exams ) {
         for (size_t i = 0; i < nStd; i++) delete[] exams[i];
         delete[] exams;
     }
}
```

For the copy you need to remember that an int** isn't the same thing as a int[][4].

```
void _Copy( const std::string * source, size_t n, std::string * dest) {
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n ; i++ ) dest[i] = source[i];  
}

template < size_t K >
    void _Copy( const int source[][K], size_t n, int ** dest) {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n ; i++ )
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < K; j++ )
                dest[i][j] = source[i][j];
}

void _Copy( int ** source, size_t n, size_t m, int ** dest) {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n ; i++ )
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < m; j++ )
                dest[i][j] = source[i][j];
}
```

Comment: If he's using `nullptr` it's presumably ok to use c++11 features.

Comment: Well, i saw a c++ tag up there... But maybe he's forced to use pointers and array.